# Array is skipping some value indices

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to iterate through an array using `for` loop. However, the indices of the values of the array I'm working is not properly structured. This means that I can find an element at index number **8**, index number **9** there's no element and the next element after **8** is at index number **11**. Example:

```
array (size=4951)
  8 => string '9,taobao.com
' (length=14)
  11 => string '10,linkedin.com
' (length=17)
  12 => string '11,amazon.com
' (length=15)
  19 => string '12,live.com
' (length=13)
```

My question is, how can I make it so that the array doesn't skip indices like this? So that when I try to iterate through the array, it will go through index **8** where it will find `9,taobao.com` and then on index **9** it would find `10,linkedin.com`. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to use `foreach` instead

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I can't use `foreach` because I need to trace which index the loop stopped at, also I need to specify an index to start iterating from. So I think `for` is the only way to start the loop from a specific index and trace that index.

Comment: then use `for` then some checking with `isset`, then you'll get to trace what index it skipped, my tip is: provide the intricacies of the problem, it may help some people answer better if you have added a note earlier

Comment: @Ghost That's fine! Thanks to @1nflktd who pointed me to use `array_values` to rearrange the array! This perfectly worked with my loop. Thanks everyone for the suggestions however!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_values`](http://au.php.net/array_values):

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

It will rearrenge all keys, starting from 0

Comment: then select as an answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Why do not use a foreach loop with key, value (if you need the key)?

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    // Treatment.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `for` and `isset` :

```
for ($i = $idx_start, $len = count($array); $i < $len; ++$i) {
  if (isset($array[$i])) {
    // Do your stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-index the array using the following function.
`$reindexed_array = array_values(array_filter($array));`
Hope it answers your question.